# React Native сборка не отправляет запрос на http сервер

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, axios

Всем привет! Я использую в своей разработке Expo. При отправке запросов, сначала использовал `fetch`, теперь перешел на `axios` (я думал, что проблема таким образом решится). Во время разработки всё работает: запросы отправляются на сервер, я получаю ответы с сервера, всё замечательно и прекрасно. Когда я собираю свое приложение в `.apk` и тестирую приложение на своем телефоне, то при отправке запроса, получаю ошибку `AxiosError: Network Error`. Вот так выглядит запрос к серверу (в целях безопасности, скрыл адрес буквой `x`):

```
await axios.post('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/reg', reg_data, {
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'
    }
})
    .then(async(response) => {
        result = {id: response.data.id, error: false}
    })
    .catch(async error => {
        result = {id: false, error}
    })
```

Проверял через Postman, тоже всё работает. Сервер на `express.js`. Если информации недостаточно, напишите в комментарии, всё покажу. Помогите мне, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вкратце: `http` нужно поменять на `https`. И в backend тоже сделать `https`.

В Android и в IOS открытый трафик блокируется. То есть в запросах к `API` вместо `http` нужно использовать `https`.

Либо отключить эту настройку в `AndroidManifest`

переходим в `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest`
устанавливает такие настройки:

```js
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic='true'
    ...
>
```

Обратите внимание на путь к манифесту, потому что часто эти настройки меняют в папке - `debug`. Такой вариант работает только на локальной версии. Именно поэтому у вас на локалке всё работает, а в 'боевой' не работает.